# TypeScript Checker Symbol Of "this"

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I have this ts.Program/ts.SourceFile:

```
class MyClass {
   foo() {
      // @1
   }
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the symbol/type of the local `this` value at position `@1`?
Unfortunately, `this` is not listed by `checker.getSymbolsInScope`.
Ideally I would get the type of `MyClass`, so I could explore its members.

The solution should also work for these cases:

```
function foo(this: MyClass) {
  // @2
}

const obj = {
  bar() {
    // @3
  }
};
```

Thank you!

---

*edit*: This is the feature I needed this for:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal `TypeChecker#tryGetThisTypeAt(nodeIn: ts.Node, includeGlobalThis = true): ts.Type` method that will return this information. If you're ok with using internal API, then you can do:

```
const type = (checker as any).tryGetThisTypeAt(nodeName) as ts.Type;
```

To get the node's name, you'll need to traverse the tree to find the method or function declaration that is contained within the position, then the `.name` property will contain the node that you can provide to `tryGetThisTypeAt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering that so quickly! That is exactly what I was looking for. Also, it seems I can pass in an arbitrary node of the context I'm interesting in.